# VB.NET 1.1 Winsock Replacement

Tags: vb.net, sockets, asynchronous, winsock

I'm trying to update an application from vb6 to vb.net. The orig app used the winsock control. Unfortunately I can't nor do I want to use it in the re-write. Are there any decent public classes with events that wrap the Socket class? I've found a few on google but all were buggy and I think it may be a little over my head to write my own from scratch.

Comment: What are the sockets used for in the application? Custom or something fairly standard?

Comment: What's wrong with `System.Net.Sockets`?  Is that what you are asking about a wrapper for?  You might be better asking specifically what your question is, as System.Net.Sockets is pretty straightforward.  Also, it is a bit more robust in later versions of the .NET Framework.  Any particular reason you need .NET 1.1?

Comment: The target environment only has 1.1 installed. My end app is going to be a kind of man in the middle of two apps that i work with, where client app connects to my app which connects to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sockets are built in now: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets(VS.71).aspx

If you are doing web related tasks then you should look at [System.Net.WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28VS.80%29.aspx) or [System.Net.HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Comment: I believe the OP is asking for something that is of a higher abstraction level than the `Socket` classes.

Comment: I've found this and am trying to modify it for my own needs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bew39x2a%28v=VS.71%29.aspx

One problem I'm have with it is the fact that it doesn't finish receiving data until the connection is closed. What would the proper procedure be to verify that all data has been received?

Comment: Unless your server tells you ahead of time how much data is being sent, then your client has no way of knowing.